# Unspecified string replacement issue

Tags: string, shell

I have an unspecified IP which I want to change a part of (the third part of it to 254 for whatever ipaddress), e.g.

```
172.16.1.2  -> 172.16.254.2<br/> 
192.168.2.6 -> 192.168.254.6<br/> 
x.x.x.x     -> x.x.254.x<br/>
```

How should I do this using shell scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed is a classic solution.

```
 sed -E -e 's/(.*)[.](.*)[.](.*)[.](.*)/\1.\2.254.\4/'
```

find something with three points and copy everything except the third which is replaced by 254.

Then use it like:

```
echo a.b.c.d  | sed -E -e 's/(.*)[.](.*)[.](.*)[.](.*)/\1.\2.254.\4/'
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I have solved the problem by using your method, though your command may not work very well on my computer, so I make it work by using a command like this: echo "1.2.3.4" | sed -e "s/\\(.*\\)[.]\\(.*\\)[.]\\(.*\\)[.]\\(.*\\)/\1.\2.254.\4/"     The sed version on my computer is "GNU sed version 4.1.5", it does not support -E option. Thank you for your help!